# REST complex response

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have created a REST service with JAX-RS and RestEasy and I have one `POST` method for it.

Here is the code for the service:

```java
@Path("/service")
public class WS {
    @POST
    @Path("/device")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendDevices(List<Device> deviceList) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        List<Device> resultList = new ArrayList<Device>();

        // response with simple message
        String message = "simple response";
        return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();
    }
}
```

I am posting an `ArrayList` of devices and at the moment I am getting a response with a `String` message which states whether the creation of the resource was successfull.

Here is a JSON I am using to test the service, which is a list with one device only:

```
[{"id": 1,
  "serial" : "s1234",
  "type":"sometype",
  "timestamp":2342344,        
}]
```

Now I want to change the response and make it more complex. So that the reponse holds two `ArrayList`s. These `ArrayList`s should hold the ids of the devices that were posted successfully (status 200) and the other list holds the ids of the devices that could not be posted successfully (status 400).

I do not know how to solve the problem though. Do I have to post each device one by one? Or how do I achieve this goal? I only know that I have to write a new class that holds 2 arrays as a field.

Comment: That doesn't fit the usual approach to implementing rest APIs. All that needs to be returned from a successful POST is the route to the new resource (document). That might be a simple id, or (in a more purist world) the full address / URI of the resource. To get the actual created resource, issue a new GET request. If you want to create multiple resources, you should (typically) submit multiple POSTs. If you prefer to do something else, you might find that the existing libraries don't make it easy.

Comment: but a REST API is all about making thing easier for the user, so in case there are 1000 devices to post...we end up with 1000 POSTs?

Comment: I don't know if Roy Fielding would agree with you on that point. Rest helps make an API consistent; when the hypermedia constraints are adhered to, it makes the API easy to expand and self-document. Nothing in it is user focused: it may be client-focused, but the clients are applications, not users. If you want to create 1000 resources \ documents with a single POST, then you have design that very carefully: the original pattern doesn't really suit it very well.